# XML to HTML in MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need a suggestion on XML response of WCF service to HTML in MVC 4.0.

Here the Response XML is a 1000 line one. I want to bind all the elements in HTML format by attaching a style sheet.

What would be the best approach here?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use XSLT, which is probably your best bet. It's not entirely clear though if you need help with the XSLT or calling the XSLT from your MVC application or both.  In either case, could you post what you've attempted and what you specifically need help with?  And if it's the XSLT you need help with, be sure to include sample input, desired output, and your attempted XSLT.

Comment: Why are you getting the results in XML? Didn't you use "Add Service Reference" in order to access the service?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, the only thing I'd say is that if they do intend to use XSLT it would make sense to call the WebService directly and get the XML (rather than a deserialization of the XML).  OF course, if they did get a class I suppose they could pass it as a model....

Comment: Yes, I am calling wcf service directly. 
To render resonse XML in required HTML XSLT would be the best approch. Is there any way i can use the razor view features here.

Comment: You could use XSLT or you could get the deserialized class, pass that as a model to a Razor view, and render it as desired in the Razor view the same way you're rendering any other model class.

Comment: As i am calling webservice directly and getting response in XML insted of generating response through my code, XSLT would be the best approach.
Thank you all for sharing your thoughts

Comment: This is why I am asking: do you already have service calls and you are "calling webservice directly"? Because that will only work with services that use `basicHttpBinding`. That won't, for instance, work with `wsHttpBinding`. Although it is one way to use XSLT, it limits you to only a single binding that you will never be able to change.

Comment: OTOH, if you are in control of the service, then you can write the service to _explicitly_ return XML. Then it won't matter which binding the service uses, since it will deliberately return XML.

Comment: Tank you for your input